# Dragging UIImageView only inside it's parent view

Tags: ios, swift

Let's say that I have:

- An `UIImageView` called `fox`
- A parent ImageView called `fence`
- Master `UIView` embedded in `ViewControllers` by default

Now in other words, I want the `fox` to move only inside it's `fence`

In my `viewDidLoad()`:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    view.addSubview(fence)
    fence.addSubview(fox)

}
```

Now this part works fine, I figured to move the `fox` by subclassing `UIImageView` with a little bit of modifications:

```
class DraggableImageView: UIImageView {


var dragStartPositionRelativeToCenter : CGPoint?

override init(image: UIImage!) {
    super.init(image: image)

    self.isUserInteractionEnabled = true 

    addGestureRecognizer(UIPanGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(handlePan(nizer:))))

    layer.shadowColor = UIColor.black.cgColor
    layer.shadowOffset = CGSize(width: 0, height: 3)
    layer.shadowOpacity = 0.5
    layer.shadowRadius = 2
}

required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
    fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
}

@objc func handlePan(nizer: UIPanGestureRecognizer!) {
    if nizer.state == UIGestureRecognizer.State.began {
        let locationInView = nizer.location(in: superview)
        dragStartPositionRelativeToCenter = CGPoint(x: locationInView.x - center.x, y: locationInView.y - center.y)

        layer.shadowOffset = CGSize(width: 0, height: 20)
        layer.shadowOpacity = 0.3
        layer.shadowRadius = 6

        return
    }

    if nizer.state == UIGestureRecognizer.State.ended {
        dragStartPositionRelativeToCenter = nil

        layer.shadowOffset = CGSize(width: 0, height: 3)
        layer.shadowOpacity = 0.5
        layer.shadowRadius = 2

        return
    }

    let locationInView = nizer.location(in: superview)

    UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.1) {
        self.center = CGPoint(x: locationInView.x - self.dragStartPositionRelativeToCenter!.x,
                              y: locationInView.y - self.dragStartPositionRelativeToCenter!.y)
    }
}}
```

Now I can drag the `fox` object anywhere i like, but; what if I wanted to only move the `fox` inside the `fence` object?, since it's a subview, I think it's possible.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In order to keep the image view inside its parent, I added a check before you update the center of the view that makes sure that the views frame will be in the parents frame. The center is only updated if the update would keep the view within its parent's frame.

I also updated the pan handler to use the translation (similar to the example in the pan gesture [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/touches_presses_and_gestures/handling_uikit_gestures/handling_pan_gestures?language=swift)) as opposed to the locationInView.
This makes the drag behave better.

I've tested this and I believe it behaves in the way you desire. Hope this helps:

```swift
    @objc func handlePan(nizer: UIPanGestureRecognizer!) {
        if nizer.state == UIGestureRecognizer.State.began {
            dragStartPositionRelativeToCenter = self.center
            layer.shadowOffset = CGSize(width: 0, height: 20)
            layer.shadowOpacity = 0.3
            layer.shadowRadius = 6

            return
        }

        if nizer.state == UIGestureRecognizer.State.ended {
            dragStartPositionRelativeToCenter = nil

            layer.shadowOffset = CGSize(width: 0, height: 3)
            layer.shadowOpacity = 0.5
            layer.shadowRadius = 2

            return
        }

        if let initialCenter = dragStartPositionRelativeToCenter {
            let translation = nizer.translation(in: self.superview)
            let newCenter = CGPoint(x: initialCenter.x + translation.x, y: initialCenter.y + translation.y)
            if frameContainsFrameFromCenter(containingFrame: superview!.frame, containedFrame: self.frame, center: newCenter) {
                UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.1) {
                    self.center = newCenter
                }
            }

        }
    }

    func frameContainsFrameFromCenter(containingFrame: CGRect, containedFrame: CGRect, center: CGPoint) -> Bool {
        let leftMargin = containedFrame.width / 2
        let topMargin = containedFrame.height / 2
        let testFrame = CGRect(
            x: leftMargin,
            y: topMargin,
            width: containingFrame.width - (2*leftMargin),
            height: containingFrame.height - (2*topMargin)
        )
        return testFrame.contains(center)
    }
```